# Generic way of sorting JSON array by attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I found out how to sort a JSON array at http://www.devcurry.com/2010/05/sorting-json-array.html

Now I want to sort it in a generic way; so that my sorting function knows which attribute to sort by.

For example if my array is

```
[
  {
    "name": "John",
    "age": "16"
  },
  {
    "name": "Charles",
    "age": "26"
  }
]
```

I want to avoid writing different if cases to know if I should sort by name or age. I just want to pass a parameter 'name' or 'age' and my sorting function should know what to do.

Thanks.

Comment: So have you tried anything? The article you linked and what you actually want to do have nothing to do with JSON, by the way; you are manipulating regular Javascript data structures, while [JSON](http://json.org) is a string serialization of such structures.

Comment: you're right. I did not formulate the question correctly.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Something like a:

```
function predicateBy(prop){
   return function(a,b){
      if (a[prop] > b[prop]){
          return 1;
      } else if(a[prop] < b[prop]){
          return -1;
      }
      return 0;
   }
}

//Usage
yourArray.sort( predicateBy("age") );
yourArray.sort( predicateBy("name") );
```

Comment: @Engineer: Is this currying ? Nice one though + 1

Comment: how is this exactly working?  what's being assigned to a and what's being assigned to b and how?

Comment: @WeDoTDD See the [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) docs

Answer (score 5):

You can sort arrays by any field with [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) library:

```
var data = [{"name":"John", "age":"16"}, {"name":"Charles", "age":"26"}];

var res1 = alasql('SELECT * FROM ? ORDER BY name',[data]);
var res2 = alasql('SELECT * FROM ? ORDER BY age',[data]);
var res3 = alasql('SELECT * FROM ? ORDER BY age, name',[data]);
var res4 = alasql('SELECT * FROM ? ORDER BY age DESC, name ASC',[data]);
```

Try this example [in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/bajjuhoz/1/).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, This helps provides all sql functionalities besides only sorting.. works wonders much thanks !! :)

Answer (score 4):

See this example 
http://jsfiddle.net/W8Byu/1/

What I have done is stored the sort column Name in a variable and used in Sort function.

```
 var sortColumnName = "Name";

 function SortByName(x,y) {
      return ((x[sortColumnName]  == y[sortColumnName]) ? 0 : ((x[sortColumnName]>    y[sortColumnName]) ? 1 : -1 ));
    }
```