# JavsaScript Object array sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays

Creating an object with two properties `address` and `distance`. Pushing this object into `darr` array.

Code:

```
var object=new Object();
object.address=add;
object.distance=distance;
darr.push(object);
```

All good till now. Now I want to sort `darr` by each object's distance. I have tried `sortOn` but it gives out no results at all. Any idea how to do this?

And just to make my mind clear. Is this some kind of associative array?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: [Generic way of sorting JSON array by attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11099679/1113426)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that, we can just use `Array.prototype.sort` in a way like

```
dart.sort(function( a, b ) {
    return a.distance - b.distance;
});
```