# Iterate through JSON based on ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am working on a webshop template and I need to display the correct JSON data according to every single product in the store in a modal that opens when clicking the given product. I am also using handlebars for templating and have the following code structure:

**.html** (button to open the modal)

```
<button type="button" class="quickview">Open Modal</button>
```

**.html** (modal)

```
<div id="quickview-modal">
 modal content that should iterate over the JSON and display one item at a time depending on the ID 
</div>
```

**.json**

```
{
 "productID" : "1",
 "name" : "productOne"
},
{
 "productID" : "2",
 "name" : "productTwo"
}
```

**.js**

```
$( ".quickview" ).click(function( event ) {
  $('#quickview-modal').modal('show');
  event.stopPropagation();
  // Do something
});
```

Any ideas how I can tackle this? Thanks!

Comment: You want to show all `json` data in `#quickview-modal`?

Comment: Sort it by `productID` and then just iterate over the sorted array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099610/generic-way-of-sorting-json-array-by-attribute

Answer (score 1):

say your .json variable is `data`

```
 var data = 'your JSON';
 $.each(data,function(i,v){
     alert(v.productID); //will give you the value related to productID.
 });
```

**updated**

```
$( ".quickview" ).click(function( event ) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   var data = 'your JSON';
   $.each(data,function(i,v){
      $('#quickview-modal').append(v.name + " : " + v.productID);

   });
   $('#quickview-modal').modal('show');
 });
```

Comment: How do I find out the right .json variable, it's a very long .json with a few levels deep nested elements?